# Randomly choose vertex points for polygons, as well as randomize the color of the overall polygon

Tags: java, graphics, colors, vertex, polygons

How should I randomize the x/y values for specific points, as well as the color of the polygons they create, in Java?
I have code I'm trying to use to create this effect, 500 times in a row, with 500 different triangles, randomizing every triangle in the same way (this is the code I'm requesting help with):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.util.Random;
public final class CRassignment34 extends Canvas
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID=99L;
  public static final void main (String[] args)
  {
    final JFrame win=new JFrame("500 randomly-selected triangles (a trainwreck indeed)");
    win.setSize(1024,768);
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    win.add(new CRlab34());
    win.setVisible(true);
  }
  public final void paint (Graphics g)
  {
    for (int i=0;i<500;i++)
    {
      final Polygon tri=new Polygon();
      final Random r=new Random();

      tri.addPoint(x,y);
      tri.addPoint(x,y);
      tri.addPoint(x,y);
      g.setColor(colorRand());
      g.fillPolygon(tri);
    }
  }
  public final void colorRand(Color c)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't currently compile. Please ask specific questions about specific things you are stuck with.

Comment: I'm currently stuck on randomizing the specific points in the 1024x768 window to use for the triangles, @tgdavies.

Comment: So each point of the triangle will need two random numbers in the appropriate ranges. Do you know how to make a random number?

Comment: Yes, I do, but I'm unsure how I should go about mapping them to the x/y locations for the triangle points.

Comment: What about just creating three random numbers between 0 and 1023 for the x coordinates of the three point, and three more random numbers between 0 and 767  for the y coordinates? I'm assuming it's OK for the triangles to overlap?